# Relative positioning of drawn elements with autolayout in iOS using Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, autolayout

I am currently working on a Xamarin iOS Application using Autolayout to position the elements inside my Views.
I want to draw elements and position them depending of other subviews that are positioned via Autolayout.

My problem is, that the `draw` method is called before the layout of the subviews is created and before they are positioned in my view, so i can't pass a relative position as the starting point to the view to be drawn.
I am only able to do this by adding the drawn subviews in the `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` not in the `ViewDidLoad` method. I think this is not a very elegant solution and I am wondering if there is any other way to position elements that have to be drawn passing a relative starting point?

Here is some example code:

A ViewController to Display the elements:

```
public class QuestionViewController : BaseController {

        private UILabel _infoLabel;
        private UIButton _button1;

        public override void ViewDidLoad() {

            UIView containerView = View;
            containerView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

            var constraints = new List<NSLayoutConstraint>();

            _infoLabel = new UILabel()
            {
                IsAccessibilityElement = true,
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
                Text = "My Info Label",
                LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap,
                Lines = 2,
                Font = UICore.TextFont,
                TextColor = UICore.TextColor
            };
            containerView.AddSubview(_infoLabel);

            constraints.Add(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(_infoLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, containerView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1f, 10f));
            constraints.Add(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(_infoLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, containerView, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1f, 10f));
            constraints.Add(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(_infoLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, containerView, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1f, -10f));

            containerView.AddConstraints(constraints.ToArray());

            base.ViewDidLoad();    
        }

        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews() {

            var containerView = View;

            var myCircle = new CircleView(new RectangleF((float)_infoLabel.Frame.X, (float)_infoLabel.Frame.Bottom, 60, 60), UIColor.Red, "TEST");
            containerView.AddSubview(myCircle);

            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
        }
    }
```

The CircleView to draw a circle:

```
public class CircleView : UIView {
        private UIColor _color;
        private string _label;

        public CircleView()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public CircleView(RectangleF bounds, UIColor color, string label) : base(bounds) {
            _label = label;
            _color = color;

            Initialize();
        }

        void Initialize()
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        }

        public override void Draw(CGRect rect) {

            var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
            context.SetFillColor(_color.CGColor);
            context.FillEllipseInRect(rect);  

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer that is working for me.

In the `ViewDidLoad` method I create another subview, add the circleView to this subview and add the subview to my containerView. The circleView gets the starting Point 0,0 and I add constraints for the subview to position it inside the containerView:

```
var dummyView = new UIView();
dummyView.AddSubview(new CircleView(new RectangleF(0f, 0f, 60, 60), UIColor.Red, "TEST");)

containerView.AddSubview(dummyView);
constraints.Add(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(dummyView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, _infoLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1f, 10f));
constraints.Add(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(dummyView, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, containerView, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1f, 10f));
```